# How to Compress and save image in Amazon server in rest API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am working on saving compressing and saving image on AWS server. Currently using PutObjectRequest of com.amazonaws.services.s3.model to save the image. I checked online and everywhere following code is used to save image on disk.

```
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
```

I am confused on how to compress it first and then send the inputstream to save in the server.
how do i compress the image in rest API and save it in AWS server?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a synchronous flow in your code where you do the compression before upload, you can follow the following approach.

- Upload the uncompressed image to S3.
- From S3 have a Lambda trigger which will be invoked upon image upload.
- In the Lambda code, download the image to the /tmp directory do the compression there and upload it back to S3.

This approach is highly scalable and a pattern used for creating thumbnails of the images & etc. (You should be able to find a Lambda template for Thumbnail creation which you can modify for this)

Comment: HI Ashan, can u please provide some reference or examples.